# Determine user destination on wp-login.php

Tags: redirect, login, wp-login-form

I am adding functionality to require users to login to view a website by hooking into the `template_redirect` action and sending non-authenticated users to wp-login. This is all working fine.

I would like to add a message to the wp-login screen for these visitors, but I do not want the message to be displayed to backend users who are also logging in through the same page. I'm using the `login_message` filter to add the text.

**Is there a way, when on the wp-login page to determine if the person is trying to login into the frontend or wp-admin?** I'm seeing a `$_REQUEST['redirect_to']` variable, but it can sometimes be empty, especially after repeated login attempts, and is just a string so would be a messy conditional.

Thanks!

Comment: On what occasion would `$_REQUEST['redirect_to']` be empty if the user comes from the frontend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use additional parameters while redirecting users from front-end.
i.e; http://yourdomain.com/wp-login.php?frontend=true

And get this parameter to check and determine whether the users have been redirected from the front-end or not.

```
if( isset($_GET['frontend']) && $GLOBALS['pagenow'] === 'wp-login.php' ) {
    echo "<h2 id='fr-msg'>Message To display</h2>";
}
```

Use this code inside your function.php or in plugin. You can use css and javascript adjustments to display the message in correct position.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#login").prepend(jQuery("#fr-msg"));
// Use as per your requirement.
}
```

This will have a dependency of jQuery hence it is necessary to include this script with a jQuery dependency. Include this in your function.php or plugin.

```
add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', function() {
wp_register_script('custom_script',  [SCRIPT_URL]/customScript.js, array('jquery'),'4.2', true);
wp_enqueue_script( 'custom_script' );
} );
```